Suppress [Vue warn]: Component <Anonymous> is missing template or render function on production
From 3rd party component we are using, we are getting
[Vue warn]: Component <Anonymous> is missing template or render function.
in the server logs on production. Is there a way to suppress these warnings? Using Nuxt 3.

See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . The question requires https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It means what it says, the component has no template, while it's expected to, or at least the framework thinks so, which ultimately matters. There could be various reasons for this, e.g. duplicated or mismatched vue versions or compiler problems. There's no way to suppress a warning for the existing problem. You need to fix it

Its caused by a 3rd party plugin which we do not control. Is there no other way to silent such errors?

You can filter a log, that's what a suppression would look like. More importantly, most times this warning indicates that a component is malfunctioning. There are way to control third-party libs, you can monkey-patch or fork them, or report problems, so they could be fixed by the maintainers. It's hard to suggest anything else without knowing the details
